# Finding $\mathbb{E}(N^2)$ where $N$ is number of tosses until we get a head

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, expected-value, variance

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> Suppose we toss a fair coin, and let $N$ denote the number of tosses until we get a head (including the final toss). What is $\mathbb{E}(N)$ and $\mathbb{E}(N^2)$?

I got that $\mathbb{E}(N) = 2$ from the equation$$\mathbb{E}(N) = {1\over2} + {1\over2}(\mathbb{E}(N) + 1).$$But how do I derive that $\mathbb{E}(N^2) = 6$?

Comment: I don't know were comes from your equation... However $N\sim Geom(1/2)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't careful enough in the previous comment. However, if $N=1$ then $N^2 = 1$. If $N\neq 1$ then $N=1+X$ where $X$ has the same distribution as $N$. Now write this as an equality using indicators, square, take the expectation, done.

Comment: In general:$$\mathbb Ef(N)=\frac12f(1)+\frac12\mathbb Ef(1+N)$$You already used that for function $x\mapsto x$. Now use it for function $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @Surb Unfamiliar? Then take notice of it. It is a very elegant route for finding expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning for the equation you wrote for $\mathbb E[N]$ is that the first toss is heads with probability $1/2$, in which case the expected number of tosses is $1$; otherwise, it is tails with probability $1/2$ in which case the expected number of tosses to get heads is $\mathbb E[N+1] = \mathbb E[N] + 1$ because the first toss was a failure.  Hence $$\mathbb E[N] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\mathbb E[N] + 1),$$ by the law of total probability.

We employ the same reasoning for $\mathbb E[N^2]$.  If the first toss is heads with probability $1/2$, then the square of the number of tosses is $1^2 = 1$; otherwise, it is tails with probability $1/2$ and the expected number of the square of tosses is $$\mathbb E[(N+1)^2] = \mathbb E[N^2] + 2\mathbb E[N] + 1.$$  Therefore

$$\mathbb E[N^2] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\mathbb E[N^2] + 2\mathbb {E}[N] + 1) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} (\mathbb {E}[N^2] + 2 \cdot 2 + 1) = 3 + \frac{\mathbb E[N^2]}{2}.$$  This yields $\mathbb E[N^2] = 6$.

Answer (score 3):

Work out:$$\mathbb E[N^2]=\frac12\cdot1^2+\frac12\mathbb E[(1+N)^2]$$